# Invalid URI: content://***/my_images/JPEG_20210524_115135_2243630097715646442.jpg

Tags: java, android, storage

I use retrofit library. when I want send picture to server , this error occurred:

```
Invalid URI: content://***/my_images/JPEG_20210524_115135_2243630097715646442.jpg
```

when user take the picture by camera, picture is saved on phone (save in external storage in special folder) but when I want send picture to server by retrofit, this method error occurred.

For receiving image path, I use this method:

```
private String getImagePath(Uri imageUri) {
    // in this method error occured:
    String wholeId = DocumentsContract . getDocumentId (imageUri);
    String id = wholeId . split (":")[1];
    String[] column ={ MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

    String sel = MediaStore . Images . Media . _ID +"=?";

    Cursor cursor = EmaratProjectApplication . getContext ().getContentResolver()
        .query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            column, sel, new String []{ id }, null);

    String filePath ="";

    int columnIndex = cursor . getColumnIndex (column[0]);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    }
    cursor.close();
    return filePath;
}
```

Comment: `getImagePath(Uri imageUri)` Please tell the value of imageUri.toString(). And tell how you obtained that uri. Further tell why you wanna oftain a file system path if you have already a nice uri.Further it is unclear when you get the invalid uri message. How did you get that uri to begin with? Please write a better post so we know what you are trying to do.